# Match names in a cell to list of names in another sheet, then return their ID's to next cell (Excel 2013)

Tags: excel, return-value, lookup

I have tried searching, but couldn't find exactly what I'm looking for (not sure if it's possible).

I have an excel sheet with a list of 200 distribution lists, and the cell next to them lists the names of every member of that DL (separated by a semicolon and space ie John Doe; Jane Doe).  I also have another sheet that lists every user we have in one column, and the column next to it lists their ID.  What I want to do is retrieve the ID of every member of each DL, and list them all in the next cell, separated by a , with no space.

For example:

```
    A         B
John Doe    203202 
Jane Doe    123002
Steve Smith 383020
```

Sheet 2:

```
    A                    B                            C
Staff List    John Doe,Jane Doe,Steve Smith  203202,123002,383020
```

So Cell C1 is what I'm trying lookup the values for.  Thank you in advance, I apologize if I wasn't very clear with what I'm looking for.

Comment: This could be done with one formula in Office 365 Excel, but in 2013, you will need helper columns and a long concatenation formula in another column.  Or you can write a UDF in vba to do it all in one.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the comment that is now deleted - but in case anyone else wants the answer:

I separated out all names in (Sheet 2) column B using "Text to Columns", then added blank row after each existing row, then under each name used the Index function to pull the ID from the Sheet 1, so then under every name was their corresponding ID.

Lastly I used the CONCATENATE and TRANSPOSE functions to combine all the ID's for each row.

Thanks for the help!